# Get value from JSON object

Tags: php, arrays, json

```
stdClass Object
(
    [form] => stdClass Object
        (
            [fieldsets] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [fieldset_name] => name_1
                            [datapoints] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [dp_id] => 4
                                        )

                                    [1] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [dp_id] => 5
                                        )
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [fieldset_name] => name_2
                            [datapoints] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [dp_id] => 1
                                        )

                                    [1] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [dp_id] => 3
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Now i want the values of dp_id seperately into two arrays ie.,array(4,5) and array(1,3)

Comment: Where does json come into this? What data do you have?

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach($object->form->fieldsets as $fieldset) {
    $dp_ids = array();
    foreach($fieldset->datapoints as $datapoint)
        $dp_ids[] = $datapoint->dp_id;
    var_dump($dp_ids);
}
```

Comment: It is returning array(3,1,4,5) but i want as array(4,5) and array(1,3)

Comment: That code should output array(4,5) and array(1,3)... You need to do something with it at the var_dump line. You can store it in some other variable for processing.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
$object->form['fieldsets'][1]->datapoints[1]
```